# Middleware function not calling the function

Tags: node.js, stylus

I am implementing stylus to my existing project. I have downloaded `'stylus'` and `nib` modules. after I implement both, the middle ware not calling the compile function at all. I am not getting any of the errors.

I believe that, some order which i am placed may be wrong or some of other methods interprting the compile function.

any one please help me to sort this issue please?

here is my app.js file functions:

```
var 
    express = require('express'),
    cons    = require('consolidate'),
    http    = require('http'),
    stylus  = require('stylus'),
    nib     = require('nib'),
    path    = require('path');

//------
var 
fs  = require("fs"),
app = express();

//adding compile function and compress
function compile(str, path) {
    console.log('path is ' + path);//I am not getting any console
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .set('compress', true)
    .use(nib());
}

// assign the underscore engine to .html files
app.engine('html', cons.underscore);

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/ui');
// app.set('env', 'development');
//app.register('.html', require('jade'));
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.favicon());
// app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
// app.use(app.router);

//adding middleware for sytlus
app.use(stylus.middleware({ // i am using the midware here / what is wrong?
    src: __dirname + '/ui',
    compile:compile,
    compress: true
}));

// // development only
// if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
//  app.use(express.errorHandler());
// }

require('amdefine/intercept');
if (typeof define !== 'function') {
    var define = require('amdefine')(module);
}

//var amdRequire = require(__dirname + "/ui/tests/config/test");
//console.log("amdRequire ========== " + amdRequire);

app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.xhr) {
        //console.log("req.path ==== " + req.path);
        var filePath = __dirname + "/ui/restResponses" + req.path + "/" + req.method;

        console.log("xhr path ------- " + filePath);
        if (req.method === "GET") {
            for (var g in req.query) {
                if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
                    console.log("GET::: req.query." + p + ": " + req.query[p] );
                }
            }
        } else if (req.method === "POST") {
            for (var p in req.body) {
                if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    console.log("POST::: req.body." + p + ": " + req.body[p] );
                }
            }

        }


        var jsFile = require(filePath);
        var response = jsFile(req, res, next);

        /*define([filePath], function (dependency) {
            console.log("dependency ==" + dependency);
        });*/

        res.send(response);

    } else {
        next();
    }
});


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ui')));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the basics: Does your HTML correctly reference a stylesheet? Does the browser send a GET for the stylesheet? What is the URL of the browser's GET request for the stylesheet? Given your filesystem layout, are you SURE the URL maps properly to the filesystem? Also run your app with `DEBUG=express:router` in the environment. You can also use a middleware that does nothing but log `req.path` then call `next()` to help you track things down.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. very thanks. I have a simple question, why the middle ware not considering the nested folders in path declaration?

Comment: The middleware will look at nested folders but since there are 2 distinct trees: the filesystem itself and the URL path, and the "root" where those join up is configurable, it is very very common for people to make a mistake such as accidentally including "/public" in the URL (which is normally only in the filesystem), etc.